# Elder Scrolls lore - Godhead in existing dream possible? Recursive dreaming?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-series

As far as I understand correctly, the whole of the Elder Scrolls universe is a dream by the Godhead that reached Amaranth.

Some people inside this universe achieved [CHIM](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/CHIM). Realizing they are part of a dream, part of one single entitity but loving themselves enough to stay a separate entity, thus being sorta like a lucid dreamer and able to shape reality/the dream.

But you are also able to achieve Amaranth which is sacrificing oneself to create a new dream, so being the dream and dreaming the dream, aka losing all powers as you are no longer knowing that you dream.

One thing I could not find an answer for is the fact that if someone achieves Amaranth inside the dream, does he create a dream inside the dream he is currently in, aka a recursive dream? Or is the dream he creates/he is, separate from the dream the new Amaranth is/was part of?

Comment: I doubt there's an official answer, but you may find this piece interesting https://www.reddit.com/r/teslore/comments/s14ew/the_amaranth/

Comment: @paul i have already read this but thanks :)

Comment: Some sources would help your question a lot.